# NavigationView set selectedItem programmatically

Tags: c#, uwp, navigation

How can I do this?

I have tried below but this doesn't work

```
NavView.SelectedItem = 1;
```

Answer (score 9):

you set an index not an item. Try this
=> you need to add using System.Linq;

```
using System.Linq;
NavView.SelectedItem = NavView.MenuItems.ElementAt(YourIndex);
```

=> If you want to select the SettingsItem

```
NavView.SelectedItem = NavView.SettingsItem;
```

Comment: Setting the SelectedItem to SettingsItem is exactly what I needed for another problem.  Up-voted this answer and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a very hacky way of doing it, is to set the `x:Name` property on the NavigationViewItem and then use (*assign*) it in the code behind.

```
NavView.SelectedItem = xNameOfItem;
```